# How to change the interval between two iterations in a task

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am making a discord bot, and I can't figure out a way to change the time interval for a task

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def auto_meme(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(meme) #handled

@commands.command()
async def start_meme(self, ctx):
   await self.auto_meme.start()
```

I tried

```py
async def auto_meme(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(meme) #handled

@commands.command()
async def start_meme(self, ctx, args: convert_to_seconds = 10):
   self.auto_meme_instance = tasks.loop(args)(self.auto_meme)
   await self.auto_meme_instance.start(ctx)
```

But when I do this, I cannot cancel or stop the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `Loop.change_interval`

```py
auto_meme.change_interval(seconds=1)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Loop.change_interval`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.change_interval)

Comment: Yes, it's the whole purpose of it